# NSLocalizedString is it really working?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslocalizedstring

I misunderstand `NSLocalizedString`.

I have a project with French and English `.strings` files.
In project target - Localizations I have 6 files in French and English.

In `english.strings` file:

```
"hello" = "world";
```

In `french.strings` file:

```
"hello" = "salut";
```

When I write a simple line of code to change label text:

```
exerciseDescription.text = NSLocalizedString(@"hello", @"no comment");
```

Output is: `hello`

I changed in iOS simulator : settings - general - international - language - French/English - Done

And output is again: `hello`

I thought it should be `world` or `salut`...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're using it in correct way but not added properly,

Localized filename should always be named `Localizable.strings`, and that file is within the particular language folder, for English, `en.lproj` and for French `fr.lproj` like wise.

Comment: The localized filename is per default `Localizable.strings`, however it can be specified by using `NSLocalizedStringFromTable`. It can be useful to use several .strings file in one project if it grows beyond a certain size.

Answer (score 2):

You are using it right, but as @Hemang mentioned you should change your filename to `Localizable.strings` as this is the default.

Furthermore I would like to suggest cleaning the build folder, and removing the application from the simulator. That helped for me in one case.

Comment: You are right. I needed a full cleaning and removing. It works very well now. Hemang and GorillaPatch big thank for time spending to help me :)