# iOS internationalisation not showing proper language

Tags: ios, xcode, internationalization, storyboard

I'm trying to internationalize my app, with xcode 4.6, but unfortunately the app keeps running  in the same language in which I started building it (italian).

I have added the extra language (english) and new storyboards and InfoPlist files have been created, however it is not working. Here's a picture that shows the files that have been created:

[image]

The simulator (v. 5.0) is running in english, so I thought the app would do the same once the english language had been added. However it still runs in italian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in my [earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16321033/nslocalizedstring-is-it-really-working/16321993#16321993) I would first remove the app from the simulator and then clean the build folder by holding option and choosing from the menu "Clean Build Folder ...".

After that rebuild your app. This helped me in some cases.

Comment: Mmmm I've tried and now when launching the app it crashes telling me `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Could not find a storyboard named 'iPhone' in bundle NSBundle`. Now I'm completely lost! :-)

Comment: Ok with some googling I found put I just had to restart Xcode! Ando for the localization, now it works as expected, thank's!