# Resource files are not displaying in Localization

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, xcode5

Only one `Resource file` is displaying When i'm adding `Localizable.strings` file for any language. My steps are,

1. Selected **My main app**'s project file in xcode and found `info` option is there
2. in `info` - `Localization` - `+` option

   Note: there is only one resource file (`InfoPlist.strings`) is available to add Language.

   3- then `Finish`, but there is no `Localizable.strings` file is displaying in xcode but there is `InfoPlist.strings` file displaying.

   But if i do these same steps in **sample app** which is working fine , I can able to select Multiple resource files And also I can see many `Localizable.strings` & `InfoPlist.strings`
   in xcode.

Like:

`Localizable.strings (English)`

`Localizable.strings (Spanish)`

`InfoPlist.Strings (English)`

`InfoPlist.Strings (Spanish)`

Can anyone please tell me the solution to add multiple resource files when localizing any language?

Comment: Do you have a Localizable.strings ? Only if one is present the languages are generated.

Comment: No Localizable.strings is there in my app and even if i drag & drop this file from another project which is not displaying in `Resource file' list.

Comment: in my project i'm using custom bundle its brand name is Default.bundle and also run scripts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make your app to support multiple languages, then you'll need to add `.strings` files to your project, make sure that you should name it "Localizable.strings" only, and need to put in particular language folder,

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16321033/nslocalizedstring-is-it-really-working/16321125#16321125) question and my answer there,

> Localized filename should always be named Localizable.strings, and that file is within the particular language folder, for English, en.lproj and for French fr.lproj like wise.

Comment: yes, I understood that but that language folder is not displaying in my project

Comment: So I drag & drop the language folders with `Localizable.strings` to my app from another project but only one is read by app not others, like en.lproj , es.lproj, fr.lproj

Comment: @Mega, if you look in project folder, one must be there, but its not added always, that's `en.lproj`. Other supported language folders you'll need to create and add manually.

Comment: yes I added manually, when i run this app if device language is `Spanish` as we need `Spanish`'s `.strings` file can read by app and displaying `Spanish` 's word but if i change the device's language to `French` still `Spanish` only coming

Comment: Yes, you'll need to rebuild the app. Its better if you can test the app in device it self.

Comment: yes i added en.lproj folder manually and I drag & drop the `Localizable.strings` into that folder, now i can this file in resource file's list. its working good by change languages frequently now when i clean build folder every time only.

Answer (score 0):

`Localizable.strings` file should be inside the `Base.lproj` folder.